# Changing Toolbar and CollapsingToolbarLayout scroll flags programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, material-design, android-support-design

I have a single Activity android app with lots of fragments. When I'm showing a list screen I want to use the `Toolbar` with the, `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"` property. And in the detail fragments I want to use the `CollapsingToolbarLayout` with an image in it. Since it's a single Activity app, I have only one `Toolbar`. Is it possible to modify my layout programmatically to suit both cases?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes. Let's say you are going from the CollapsingToolbarLayout fragment to the Toolbar one.

1. You collapse your `AppBarLayout` using `AppBarLayout.setExpanded(false)`;
2. You change the scroll flags to fit your needs.

   ```
   AppBarLayout.LayoutParams p = (AppBarLayout.LayoutParams) toolbar.getLayoutParams();
   p.setScrollFlags(...);
   toolbar.setLayoutParams(p);
   ```

   Same goes for the CollapsingToolbarLayout if necessary. I guess it should be something like:

   ```
   collapsingToolbarParams.setScrollFlags(0); //no flags for ctl
   toolbarParams.setScrollFlags(SCROLL_FLAG_SCROLL | SCROLL_FLAG_ENTER_ALWAYS); //new flags for toolbar
   ```

Comment: I also had this problem. Seems that I forgot to call the `setLayoutParams()` method. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: setScrollFlags(0) works fine but when I try to set it to this: params.setScrollFlags(AppBarLayout.LayoutParams.SCROLL_FLAG_ENTER_ALWAYS | AppBarLayout.LayoutParams.SCROLL_FLAG_SNAP);  // clear all scroll flags
                 toolbar.setLayoutParams(params); doesn't work..

Answer (score 11):

> I found it working

```
public void disableToolBarScrolling() {
    CollapsingToolbarLayout toolbar = findViewById(R.id.collap_toolbar);
    AppBarLayout.LayoutParams params = (AppBarLayout.LayoutParams) toolbar.getLayoutParams();
    params.setScrollFlags(0);
}

public void enableToolBarScrolling() {
    CollapsingToolbarLayout toolbar = findViewById(R.id.collap_toolbar);
    AppBarLayout.LayoutParams params = (AppBarLayout.LayoutParams) toolbar.getLayoutParams();
    params.setScrollFlags(SCROLL_FLAG_SCROLL | SCROLL_FLAG_ENTER_ALWAYS);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Works for me.

```
public void enableToolBarScrolling(CollapsingToolbarLayout toolbar) {
    AppBarLayout.LayoutParams params = (AppBarLayout.LayoutParams) toolbar.getLayoutParams();
    params.setScrollFlags(SCROLL_FLAG_SCROLL | SCROLL_FLAG_ENTER_ALWAYS);
    toolbar.setLayoutParams(params);
}
```