# RecyclerView scrolling glitches when disabling AppBarLayout in a CoordinatorLayout?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-coordinatorlayout

**Background**

I have a `CoordinatorLayout` based view, which has an `AppbarLayout` and `RecyclerView` as direct children. The `AppBarLayout` houses a search bar that collapses when you scroll the `RecyclerView` up. The XML for this view is:

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/search_coordinator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/search_app_bar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            app:elevation="0dp">

        <!-- Search bar -->
        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/search_constraint"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlwaysCollapsed|snap">

            <!-- Abbreviated -->
            <EditText .../>

            <!-- Abbreviated -->
            <ImageView .../>

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <!-- List -->
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/scroll_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

When you tap on the `EditText` view in the search bar, that enables what I call "Search Mode". All that search mode does is disable the `AppBarLayout` from collapsing when scrolling the `RecyclerView`. The user can then type into the search bar - which filters the items in the `RecyclerView` - and then they can scroll the list without the search bar collapsing. I hook into the `EditText` `onFocus` events to perform this:

```
searchField.setOnFocusChangeListener { _, hasFocus ->
    if (hasFocus) {
        // When user taps the search bar, enable search mode
        enableSearchMode()
    }
}
```

And the `enableSearchMode` code is:

```
private fun enableSearchMode() {
    ...

    itemRecyclerView.isNestedScrollingEnabled = false

    ...
}
```

**Problem**

This setup seems to work perfectly... most of the time. Randomly - maybe 1% of the time - when you touch the `EditText` to enable search mode, something goes wrong and I'm not able to effectively scroll the `RecyclerView` anymore. It is like it is stuck at the top of the list. If you try to scroll towards the bottom of the list, the scrolling jerks around, and generally jumps back up to the top of the list. As soon as the search mode is disabled, the problem goes away.

```
// Disable search mode
itemRecyclerView.isNestedScrollingEnabled = true
```

Despite an enormous amount of testing, I have not been able to consistently reproduce the issue or determine what progression of actions leads to it. It just randomly happens, as if there is some sort of race condition going on within the `CoordinatorLayout`.

I have stripped away so much code in my app to isolate the issue that I am confident the issue occurs precisely when I set `isNestedScrollingEnabled` to false. That said, I have also tried an alternative to disabling the `AppBarLayout` from moving when the `RecyclerView` is scrolled, which is to override the behavior of the `AppBarLayout` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49735130/5108909). Oddly enough, this leads to the same problem. If I don't disable the `AppBarLayout` either through this means or via setting `isNestedScrollingEnabled` false, the issue never appears.

What is happening here?!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is happening here?!?

Setting `isNestedScrollingEnabled` to false, in fact, breaks the communication between your `itemRecyclerView` as **scrolling child** and `AppBarLayout` as **it's parent**. The normal behaviour is `itemRecyclerView` notifies it's parent `AppBarLayout` it's scrolling progress for which the parent is supposed to react to it by **calculating it's collapsed height given any scrolling progress and all other stuffs**.
I found somewhere that setting `isNestedScrollingEnabled` to false would cause the `RecyclerView` to **not recycle** its views. I can't say exactly if it's true but if it is then, I think it's cause for that glitch.

The solution that I would like to propose is to change the `scroll_flags` programmatically to `NO_SCROLL` so that `AppBarLayout` wouldn't react/scroll in scrolling of its child scrolling view.
Although, it's in java but following code snippet should help you.

```
            // get a reference for your constraint layout
            ConstraintLayout constraintLayout = findViewById(R.id.search_constraint);
            // get the layout params object to change the scroll flags programmatically
            final AppBarLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (AppBarLayout.LayoutParams) constraintLayout.getLayoutParams();
    
            // flags variable to switch between
            final int noScrollFlags = AppBarLayout.LayoutParams.SCROLL_FLAG_NO_SCROLL;
            final int defaultScrollFlags = AppBarLayout.LayoutParams.SCROLL_FLAG_SCROLL 
                | AppBarLayout.LayoutParams.SCROLL_FLAG_ENTER_ALWAYS_COLLAPSED
                | AppBarLayout.LayoutParams.SCROLL_FLAG_SNAP;

        // now we will set appropriate scroll flags according to the focus
        searchField.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                layoutParams.setScrollFlags(hasFocus ? noScrollFlags : defaultScrollFlags);
            }
        });
```

Comment: What about a scenario where I want the `AppBarLayout` to be collapsed, but also disabled? Currently, if I change the flags to `NO_SCROLL` when the app bar is already collapsed, it instantly expands fully without animation, even though I want it to be collapsed.

Comment: So, even if `AppBarLayout` is collapsed, the `EditText` is still visible ? Can I see your UI once when `AppBarLayout` is collapsed ?

Comment: Sorry that wasn't clear. When the `AppBarLayout` is collapsed the `EditText` should be hidden. All that remains visible from a UI perspective is the `RecyclerView`. I.e. if I call `appBarLayout.setExpanded(false)` the `EditText` animates and collapses, and can no longer be seen. But, once it is collapsed, if I set the flags to `NO_SCROLL` as you mentioned, it's not possible for the `AppBarLayout` to remain collapsed. It instantly goes back to it's full expanded height when I set the flags.

Comment: I only mentioned to use `NO_SCROLL` flag to prevent the `AppBarLayout` from being `collapsed` when `searchField` has focus and that's what you have asked in the question I think. If my answer actually answers to your that problem then you should accept the answer and create a new thread for this problem according to SO rules. Sorry if I sound rude.

Comment: Also, if `AppBarLayout` is `collapsed`, and you wouldn't want `AppBarLayout` to react to scroll, then your `searchField` is never to be seen. So, user wouldn't be able to filter the results. I think that would made a bad UX. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: While I didn't mention it in the question, I was hoping that what worked for locking an `AppBarLayout` open would also work to keep one locked closed. Keeping it locked closed is for a different use case in the app (as you mentioned, doesn't make sense for the search bar) but I thought it would be easier to ask within this context.

Comment: In reality, I actually have nested `CoordinatorLayouts`. The parent needs to be locked closed (has a header to be hidden) and the child needs to be locked open (the search bar). It's a fairly complex view, but I can't confidently say that your solution fixes my problem yet because the bug still appears to be showing up. That's likely happening in the parent `CoordinatorLayout` where I can't use the scroll flags, but I haven't had the time to strip away the parent coordinator to isolate the coordinator with the search bar, thus I haven't marked the question as answered. I will once I have time.

Comment: Oh!, I didn't know you had a nested `CoordinatorLayout`. I tried in a single `CoordinatorLayout` and written the answer based on that. But, it is bad practice to use nested layouts in terms of performance. I want to recommend you to try and reduce one `CoordinatorLayout`.